# There is a way to get the feed of an user via the open graph api of facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get the feed of an specific user via the open graph api of facebook, the feed that I'm sayings isn't about the posts that the user own, instead is the feed of the posts of the friends of the user. I think that maybe I can get the friends list of the user and then find the posts of the user's friends, but I can't get the post of the user friends.
I'm using meteor in the development of the site.

Comment: No you can't. You can only get posts from users that granted you user_posts permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can get the Id's of the users friends and then get their feed but you'll still have to get their friend's permission before you can  read the post so No would be the answer to your question here.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/feed